# What is the new way of getting all methods of a class, including inherited default methods of Java 8?

Tags: java, inheritance, reflection, java-8

I want to get all methods of a class, including public, protected, package and private methods, and including inherited methods.

Remember:

- `Class.getDeclaredMethods()` gets public, protected, package and private
  methods, **but** excludes inherited methods.
- `Class.getMethods` gets inherited methods, **but** only the public ones.

Before Java 8 we could do something along the lines of:

```
Collection<Method> found = new ArrayList<Method>();
while (clazz != null) {
    for (Method m1 : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        boolean overridden = false;

        for (Method m2 : found) {
            if (m2.getName().equals(m1.getName())
              && Arrays.deepEquals(m1.getParameterTypes(), m2
                  .getParameterTypes())) {
            overridden = true;
            break;
            }
        }
        if (!overridden) found.add(m1);
    }

    clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
}
return found;
```

But now, if the class implements some interface with **default methods** which are not overridden by concrete superclasses, these methods will escape the above detection. Besides, there are now rules concerning default methods with the same name, and these rules must be taken into account as well.

**Question:** What is the current recommended way of getting **all** methods of a class:

The most common definition of "all" should be the methods that can be directly accessed inside an instance method of the class, without the use of `super` or class names:

- Include public, protected, package and private methods declared in the class itself.
- Include protected methods of its superclasses.
- Include package methods of its superclasses of the same package.
- Include default methods of its interfaces (those not overridden/hidden, see [here](http://www.lambdafaq.org/how-are-conflicting-method-declarations-resolved/) and [here](http://www.lambdafaq.org/what-about-the-diamond-problem/)).
- Include static methods (class and superclasses) with the appropriate accessibility.
- Don't include private methods of superclasses.
- Don't include overridden methods.
- Don't include hidden methods (in special, don't include hidden static methods).
- Don't include synthetic/bridge methods.
- Don't include methods not allowed by Java, even if the JVM allows them.

So, the above definition fits the following signature when both boolean flags are `false`:

```
public Collection<Method> getAllMethods(Class clazz,
                               boolean includeAllPackageAndPrivateMethodsOfSuperclasses,
                               boolean includeOverridenAndHidden)
```

The ideal, canonical answer, should allow for these boolean flags.

Comment: Are you sure that the way of getting all methods of a class which worked up until java 7 is not sufficient anymore?  Do you have an example where it is not?

Comment: @MikeNakis, try it yourself. Default methods (without overridden implementations) won't show up.

Comment: well, they are not really declared methods, so I would not expect getDeclartedMethods() to fetch them, but doesn't getMethods() fetch them?

Comment: Okay, I guess I can agree to this: you will not see default methods of an object in the scenario where you only use getDeclaredMethods() and recurse-to-super to collect all methods.  This particular approach used to work and will not work anymore, I suppose.  Right?

Comment: @aioobe what happened to your answer?  I did not mean you to remove your answer.  This is a good question and I think you had a good answer.

Comment: I can't let it stand if I don't know it's 100% correct. If I find time to revise, I'll do that and then undelete it. There were two issues I hadn't thought about when writing it: getMethods() does indeed return inherited default methods, and I didn't really put any effort in dealing with multiple inherited methods of same signature. I think the way forward is to let getMethods resolve this, but then one has to complement the result with getDeclaredMethods, and things may get a bit messy.

Comment: My friend and colleague [Joel Borggrén-Franck](http://stackoverflow.com/users/38222/joel-borggr%C3%A9n-franck) wrote the OpenJDK implementation of getMethods and he can attest that it is indeed messy. In fact he asked me to point you to an earlier email discussion [here](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2014-May/026782.html).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Even for the “Before Java 8” scenario, your code snippet isn’t correct. But collecting *all* methods isn’t a usual scenario though, as you normally need methods regarding a certain context, e.g. you might want to know which methods are *accessible* for a given context, which doesn’t include all methods, even if you consider non-`public` methods. If you really want *all* methods, you have to recall that `private` and `static` methods are never overridden and package-private methods are only overridden when being declared within the same `package`. So it’s not correct to filter every encountered method signature.

What makes matters worse is that methods might get overridden with different modifiers. The latter can be solved by keeping the idea to start at the actual class and use `Class.getMethods()` to get all `public` method including `default` methods and traverse the superclass hierarchy towards `java.lang.Object` so the already encountered overrides have the least restrictive access modifiers.

As a side note, nesting linear search loops is never a good idea. You’ll soon end up with a quadratic or worse complexity.

You may collect methods using the following method:

```
public static Set<Method> getAllMethods(Class<?> cl) {
    Set<Method> methods=new LinkedHashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(methods, cl.getMethods());
    Map<Object,Set<Package>> types=new HashMap<>();
    final Set<Package> pkgIndependent = Collections.emptySet();
    for(Method m: methods) types.put(methodKey(m), pkgIndependent);
    for(Class<?> current=cl; current!=null; current=current.getSuperclass()) {
        for(Method m: current.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            final int mod = m.getModifiers(),
                access=Modifier.PUBLIC|Modifier.PROTECTED|Modifier.PRIVATE;
            if(!Modifier.isStatic(mod)) switch(mod&access) {
                case Modifier.PUBLIC: continue;
                default:
                    Set<Package> pkg=
                        types.computeIfAbsent(methodKey(m), key -> new HashSet<>());
                    if(pkg!=pkgIndependent && pkg.add(current.getPackage())) break;
                    else continue;
                case Modifier.PROTECTED:
                    if(types.putIfAbsent(methodKey(m), pkgIndependent)!=null) continue;
                    // otherwise fall-through
                case Modifier.PRIVATE:
            }
            methods.add(m);
        }
    }
    return methods;
}

private static Object methodKey(Method m) {
    return Arrays.asList(m.getName(),
        MethodType.methodType(m.getReturnType(), m.getParameterTypes()));
}
```

But as said, it might be the case that it isn’t suitable for whatever you want to do. You should ask yourself the following questions first:

- Are you looking for methods that make up the API (that’s usually `public` and `protected` only)?
- Or do you want to actually see methods accessible for a certain `class`/`package` context?
- Shall `static` methods be included?
- Shall synthetic/bridge methods be included?
- etc.

---

Here is the revised method adapted to your more specific request:

```
public static Collection<Method> getAllMethods(Class clazz,
                boolean includeAllPackageAndPrivateMethodsOfSuperclasses,
                boolean includeOverridenAndHidden) {

    Predicate<Method> include = m -> !m.isBridge() && !m.isSynthetic() &&
         Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(m.getName().charAt(0))
      && m.getName().chars().skip(1).allMatch(Character::isJavaIdentifierPart);

    Set<Method> methods = new LinkedHashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(methods, clazz.getMethods());
    methods.removeIf(include.negate());
    Stream.of(clazz.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(include).forEach(methods::add);

    final int access=Modifier.PUBLIC|Modifier.PROTECTED|Modifier.PRIVATE;

    Package p = clazz.getPackage();
    if(!includeAllPackageAndPrivateMethodsOfSuperclasses) {
        int pass = includeOverridenAndHidden?
            Modifier.PUBLIC|Modifier.PROTECTED: Modifier.PROTECTED;
        include = include.and(m -> { int mod = m.getModifiers();
            return (mod&pass)!=0
                || (mod&access)==0 && m.getDeclaringClass().getPackage()==p;
        });
    }
    if(!includeOverridenAndHidden) {
        Map<Object,Set<Package>> types = new HashMap<>();
        final Set<Package> pkgIndependent = Collections.emptySet();
        for(Method m: methods) {
            int acc=m.getModifiers()&access;
            if(acc==Modifier.PRIVATE) continue;
            if(acc!=0) types.put(methodKey(m), pkgIndependent);
            else types.computeIfAbsent(methodKey(m),x->new HashSet<>()).add(p);
        }
        include = include.and(m -> { int acc = m.getModifiers()&access;
            return acc!=0? acc==Modifier.PRIVATE
                    || types.putIfAbsent(methodKey(m), pkgIndependent)==null:
                noPkgOverride(m, types, pkgIndependent);
        });
    }
    for(clazz=clazz.getSuperclass(); clazz!=null; clazz=clazz.getSuperclass())
        Stream.of(clazz.getDeclaredMethods()).filter(include).forEach(methods::add);
    return methods;
}
static boolean noPkgOverride(
        Method m, Map<Object,Set<Package>> types, Set<Package> pkgIndependent) {
    Set<Package> pkg = types.computeIfAbsent(methodKey(m), key -> new HashSet<>());
    return pkg!=pkgIndependent && pkg.add(m.getDeclaringClass().getPackage());
}
private static Object methodKey(Method m) {
    return Arrays.asList(m.getName(),
        MethodType.methodType(m.getReturnType(), m.getParameterTypes()));
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know the snippet is not correct, that's why I said "something along the lines of". Anyway, the definition of "all methods" must indeed be more precise for an answer to make any sense. I have edited my question to add this precision, so that a canonical answer to this question may be useful to most people. Feel free to suggest modifications if you think the the definition of "all methods" is still not precise enough.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to accept your answer. For the Brazilian Carnival I went to a small island that was supposed to have internet connection but did not, and I only came back to Rio yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to compile Holger's answer in an Android environment since `MethodType` is added in API level 26 and Android Studio supports a subset of Java 8 Language Features. In addition to this, Holger's code contains to much lambdas and streams, I consider those as human unreadable. So I decided to write a more readable code that works in any Java environment. But it's not an ideal solution since I did not include the flags.

**Below snippets work same as if you called `getAllMethods(clazz, false, false)`**

```
private static Collection<Method> getAllMethods(Class<?> target) {
    Class<?> clazz = target;
    Collection<MethodSignature> methodSignatures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        addIfAbsentAndNonSynthetic(methodSignatures, method);
    }
    for(Method method : clazz.getMethods()) {
        addIfAbsentAndNonSynthetic(methodSignatures, method);
    }
    Package pkg = clazz.getPackage();
    clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    while(clazz != null) {
        for(Method method : clazz.getDeclaredMethods()) {
            int modifier = method.getModifiers();
            if(Modifier.isPrivate(modifier)) {
                continue;
            }
            if(Modifier.isPublic(modifier) || Modifier.isProtected(modifier)) {
                addIfAbsentAndNonSynthetic(methodSignatures, method);
            }
            else if((pkg != null && pkg.equals(clazz.getPackage())) || (pkg == null
                    && clazz.getPackage() == null)) {
                addIfAbsentAndNonSynthetic(methodSignatures, method);
            }
        }
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    }
    Collection<Method> allMethods = new ArrayList<>(methodSignatures.size());
    for(MethodSignature methodSignature : methodSignatures) {
        allMethods.add(methodSignature.getMethod());
    }
    return allMethods;
}

private static void addIfAbsentAndNonSynthetic(Collection<MethodSignature> collection,
        Method method) {
    MethodSignature methodSignature = new MethodSignature(method);
    if(!method.isSynthetic() && !collection.contains(methodSignature)) {
        collection.add(methodSignature);
    }
}
```

Two of the components of a method declaration comprise the method signature: The method's name and the parameter types. The compiler does not consider return type when differentiating methods, so you can not declare two methods with the same signature even if they have a different return type. So `MethodSignature` class does not hold any reference to the return type of it's method.

But when you invoke `getDeclaredMethods` or `getMethods` it is possible to get multiple declared methods with the same name and parameter types, but different return types. This means that the compiler created a synthetic method, called a bridge method. To solve this problem, invoke `method.isSynthetic()` on the method, if it returns true skip it. Since it is a synthetic method there will be a non synthetic one with the same signature but different return type.

```
public class MethodSignature {
    private final Method mMethod;
    private final String mName;
    private final Class<?>[] mParameterTypes;

    public MethodSignature(Method method) {
        mMethod = method;
        mName = mMethod.getName();
        mParameterTypes = mMethod.getParameterTypes();
    }

    public Method getMethod() {
        return mMethod;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public Class<?>[] getParameterTypes() {
        return mParameterTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        if(this == object) {
            return true;
        }
        if(object == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if(!getClass().equals(object.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        MethodSignature obj = (MethodSignature) object;
        if(hashCode() != obj.hashCode()) {
            return false;
        }
        return mName.equals(obj.getName()) && Arrays
                .equals(mParameterTypes, obj.getParameterTypes());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 11;
        hash = 37 * hash + Objects.hash(mName, Arrays.hashCode(mParameterTypes));
        return hash;
    }
}
```